# Why uploaded images do not display?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I uploaded an image via form to `/App_Data/uploads/img-name.jpg`

In the View I make:

```
<img src="~/App_Data/uploads/@(Model.Photo).jpg">
```

But the image does not appear.

If I try to view it via link (`http://localhost:00000/App_Data/uploads/img-name.jpg`) it says:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App_Data is a protected folder that is hidden from browsing. You would need to make an action on a controller that returns the data.

```
public class DownloadController
{
    public ActionResult Upload(string name)
    {
        return File(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads/" + name + ".jpg"), "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I put to another folder (maybe `~/uploads/`)?

Comment: I changed the location and it worked. I will accept your answer though.